# What is the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^2$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

I was wondering about this problem. If we consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a $\mathbb{R}$ vector space it has dimension 2. What if we consider it a $\mathbb{F}_3$ vector space? I thought about the following thing:

If we want to generate $\begin{pmatrix} 7 \\ 8\end{pmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^2$ using the standard basis $\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\right\}$, a sum like $\sum_{i=0}^2 a_i e_i$ with $a_i\in\mathbb{F}_3$ will not be sufficient since we the maximum we can obtain is clearly $\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}$. So in my opinion the dimension should be greater than 2.

I don't know why, but I got the feeling that maybe $\text{dim}_{\mathbb{F}_3}\mathbb{R}^2=\text{dim}_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{R}^2\cdot\text{dim}_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{F}_3$.

Thank you in advance

A.

Comment: We can't consider it as a vector space over any finite field.

Comment: How do you define a $\mathbb{F}_3$-\verctor space structure in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: "the maximum we can obtain" No. $2$ is not the largest element in $\Bbb F_3$. The elements $2$ and $-1$ are the _same_, how can you justify whether it's larger than or less than $1$ or $0$? There is no largest element. The elements in $\Bbb F_3$ do not lie on a line, they lie in a circle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have $\Bbb R^2$, with regular addition, be a vector space over $\Bbb F_3$. It's simply not possible to fulfill the axioms.

Specifically, take the axiom that says

> For each vector $x$ and any two scalars $a, b$, we have $(a+b)x = ax + bx$

Now let $a = 1, b = 2$, and see what happens.

If you try to salvage this by saying "we define scalar multiplication by $2$ to make this work", then you run into trouble with $a = b = 1$ instead. And you can't salvage it by changing how the scalar multiplication with $1$ works, because scalar multiplication by $1$ is uniquely defined by another axiom.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft That's the formal nail in the coffin, but even without that axiom one can smell trouble from realizing that $\forall x : 1x+2x = 0$. Taking it one step further, with $2 = 1+1$ we get that $1x+1x+1x = 0$, which means that $1x = 0$. This directly contradicts $1x = x$, but even if we discard that axiom and accept this consequence, it looks really ugly.

Comment: I see your point, but vector space's axioms does not say $ 1x \neq 0 $, at least in the definition I learned. Could it be that this vector space is just the trivial one, that just contains the 0 vector.

Comment: @albpesc Have you forgotten your own question? The vector space is $\Bbb R^2$. It has uncountably many elements, and must therefore by a counting argument contain elements other than the $0$ vector. With the axiom that $1x = x$ for all $x$, we have concluded that if there is a real vector space which, with the same addition operation, can also be given a scalar multiplication from $\Bbb F_3$, then such a space has $1x = 0$ for all $x$. And since $1x = x$ is a vector space axiom, we have $x = 0$ for all $x$. Which is to say, it can only be the trivial vector space, which is not $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: My comment was about: maybe considering $\mathbb{R}^2$ as $\mathbb{F}_3$ vector space, it is indeed the trivial vector space. Not just because we imagine it as infinite because we think about it as a $\mathbb{R}$ vector space, this does not prove that as $\mathbb{F}_3$ vector space it has to have infinite elements. In my opinion if you change the field you change drastically the vector space.

Comment: @albpesc Considering that you will have to drastically change the addition operation in order to ever make it into a vector space over the other field, yes, it will drastically change the vector spcae. It will bear no resemblance to whatever vector field it was before except that the elements will happen to have the same names. There is no reason to expect that in this new vector space we have $(1, 0) + (0,1) = (1, 1)$, for instance. It can happen, especially if you make it so, but then I can just find another such relation that isn't true.

Comment: @albpesc "[...] this does not prove that as $\mathbb{F}_3$ vector space it has to have infinite elements." You have a fundamental misunderstanding here. "Having infinitely many elements" is not really a property of a vector space, it is a property of the underlying set ($\mathbb{R}^2$ in this case). You can define operations in any way you want on the set $\mathbb{R}^2$ to make it a vector space over any field you want (as long as its cardinality is less than that of $\mathbb{R}$), but as a set it will always be infinite.